# Generic Type in Swift as Return Value

Tags: swift, generics

I would like to implement some code so that I can call something like:

```
NSUserDefaults("key1", "value1")
let s = NSUserDefaults("key1") // "value1" expected
NSUserDefaults("key2", 2.01)
let s = NSUserDefaults("key2") // 2.01 expected
```

I have some code in concept as below, but obviously it's not going to work. So my question is, instead of writing a series of functions like `class func bool(key: String, _ v: Bool? = nil) -> Bool?` is there any way to take the advantage of generic please?

```
extension NSUserDefaults {
    class func object<T: AnyObject>(key: String, _ v: T? = nil) -> T? {
        if let obj: T = v {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(obj, forKey: key)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        } else {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key) as T?
        }
        return v
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is going to wind up being very poor. This line can't work as written:

```
let s = NSUserDefaults("key1") // "value1" expected
```

Swift has to pick a type for `s` at compile time, not run time. So the only type it can assign here is `Any` (not even `AnyObject` is expansive enough if you want to return `Double` since `Double` is not `AnyObject`).

That means you have to explicitly call out `let s : Any = ...` (because Swift wisely won't let you create `Any` implicitly), and then you're going to wind up with an `Any` that you have to type-check somehow. When you're done, you're going to come full circle to `objectForKey()`.

Even if you could get this syntax working, you shouldn't try to overload a single function syntax to do opposite things. That's very confusing. If you were going to build an extension like this, you should probably make it a subscript. That way you'd say `defaults["key1"]` and `defaults["key2"] = 2.01`. That's something may be able to build (though there will still be type annotation headaches required to deal with `AnyObject?`).